# Matplotlib: enlarge, populate, and center legend in stacked up pie charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, pie-chart, legend-properties

I have a code block which produces vertically aligned pie charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

labels=['Ph 1', 'Ph 2','Ph 3']
colors = ['darkred', 'gold', 'green']
explode = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
event1=numpy.array([93.90,0.45,5.65])
event2=numpy.array([82.96,0.86,16.17])
event3=numpy.array([69.25,1.20,29.55])
fig1, (ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(3,1,subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
ax2.legend(labels, loc=(-0.05, 0.05), shadow=True)
ax1.pie(event1, explode=explode, colors=colors)
ax2.pie(event2, explode=explode, colors=colors)
ax3.pie(event3, explode=explode, colors=colors)
plt.show()
```

I want the legend to be aligned to the central pie, but to be placed to its left. As of now, I get a very small legend which is **empty**, **unreadable**, and **in the wrong location**. How to fix that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using patches as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy

labels= ['Ph 1', 'Ph 2', 'Ph 3']
colors = ['darkred', 'gold', 'green']
explode = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
event1=numpy.array([93.90,0.45,5.65])
event2=numpy.array([82.96,0.86,16.17])
event3=numpy.array([69.25,1.20,29.55])
fig1, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1,subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})

ph1 = mpatches.Patch(color='darkred', label='Ph 1')
ph2 = mpatches.Patch(color='gold', label='Ph 2')
ph3 = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Ph 3')

ax2.legend(handles=[ph1, ph2, ph3], fontsize=15, loc=(-1.05, 0.15), shadow=True)

ax1.pie(event1, explode=explode, colors=colors)
ax2.pie(event2, explode=explode, colors=colors)
ax3.pie(event3, explode=explode, colors=colors)
plt.show()
```

This would display as follows:
[image]

Comment: Adding `plt.tight_layout()` before the show would help.

Comment: Yup! Thanks! I guess I could use `mpatches` to add text labels to the right of each pie. Correct?

Comment: You could look at the `annotate` function.